# Bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a database `goods` with two columns `id jsonb primary_key` and `name`.
Using this query:

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO "goods" (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)'
```

together with the following data:

```
const data = {id: 1, name: "milk"};
```

gives me the following error:

```
{ [error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2]
  name: 'error',
  length: 130,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '08P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'postgres.c',
  line: '1556',
  routine: 'exec_bind_message' }
```

I have a postgres database set up, connected via pg.Pool() and executing javascript to insert my data.

Edit:
This is how I prepare my query:

```
pool.query(query, [data]).then(() => {
    console.log("ok")
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Edit2:

Using the following:

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO "goods" (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)'
const data = JSON.stringify([1, "milk"]);
pool.query(query, data).then(() => {
    console.log("ok")
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Just spits out the following error: `[TypeError: self.values.map is not a function]`

Comment: can you show how are you preparing and executing query?

Comment: `client.query()` string please, probably you try to put json object `{id: 1, name: "milk"}` instead of array with values `[1,"milk"]`

Comment: @PriyeshKumar I edited my answer.

Comment: To any fellow Google-wanderers: `prepared statement ""` does _not_ mean that the query was not read in correctly. I don't know why it prints an empty string, but it's not the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [docs](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#method-query-parameterized), parameters must be JavaScript object (which is array). So you don't need to stringify `data`

Try this:

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO goods (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)'

const data = [1, "milk"];

pool.query(query, data).then(....)
```

Or

```
pool.query({ 
    text: 'INSERT INTO goods (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)', 
    values: [1, 'milk']
 }).then(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query), a Prepared Statement expects an array of values, not an object with properties, i.e. your data must be: `const data = [1, "milk"];`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, another problem occurs now: [error: invalid input syntax for type json]

Comment: @optional that's a different issue, for which you need to provide details also.

Comment: I forgot to remove the "[" "]" braces of the data when passed to the query after already adding them to the const data.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that i put my placeholder value in single quotes.

So instead of:

```
const query = {
    text: "SELECT email, password from users WHERE email='$1'",
    values: [data.email],
};
```

Do this:

```
const query = {
     text: "SELECT email, password from users WHERE email=$1", // -> here is the difference
     values: [data.email],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using slonik.

## Don't use interpolation

**Don't do this!**

```js
connection.query(sql`
  SELECT 1
  FROM foo
  WHERE bar = ${baz}
`);
```

## Use value placeholders

**Do this - wrap variable with single quote**

```js
connection.query(sql`
  SELECT 1
  FROM foo
  WHERE bar = ${'baz'}
`);
```

Comment: can you explain more?